# Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532) when I add data to object

Tags: typescript

I creted object and property formTemplateValues. I have this property with 100% guarantee, but I see error: "Object is possibly 'undefined'". It can't be undefited, because I created it. Why did I have this error and how can I fix it?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwLABQyyMA9lALboUAOANnJAGpx0CumA-AFy6HHEwcAEYARRnB58iAwcAoQAkuGgA3VlKxRQAcwDc-WcgC%20BmcWMBtALpnjhQnQjY4vdFmQBeaQEgylanpGCBZ2TF4bQh9TBwI4ADp-KghaBmZWDgxLAAZrL18hMQlefHMBMHklFSh1Ol4AIgATZsb6qPsCYyA)

```js
interface Test {
  formTemplateValues?: {
    tabData?: {
      timeInterval?: string;
      };
    }[];
}

let a: Test = {
    formTemplateValues: []
    };

a.formTemplateValues[0] = {  // Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
    tabData: {
      timeInterval: "dddd"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is relying on the type definition you've given for the type which says the field may be missing:

```
interface Test {
  formTemplateValues?: {
  // ---------------^
    tabData?: {
      timeInterval?: string;
    };
  }[];
}
```

When you then have the assignment with the annotated type `Test`, the optional type is kept, even though you assigned a value.

```
const a: Test = {
  // This is still considered possibly undefined
  formTemplateValues: []
};
```

If the field will always be there as you said, you could remove the optional from the type definition.
Alternatively, you can either check for the field before adding, or lift up the inner field to a separate type and leave the variable type inferred:

```
interface TemplateValue {
  tabData?: {
    timeInterval?: string;
  };
};

const a = {
  formTemplateValues: [] as TemplateValue[]
};
```